# Preferred method to reduce/filter a Map in Dart?

Tags: dictionary, dart

Trying to find the cleanest way to reduce a Map in Dart. Looking for something akin to JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Any suggestions? The following method leaves a lot to be desired:

```
Map ingredients = {
  'flour': '250g',
  'butter': '50g',
  'egg': 1,
  'water': '0.2l'
};

final flour = new Map.fromIterable(
  ingredients.keys.where((k) => ingredients[k] == '250g'),
  value: (k) => ingredients[k]
);

print(flour); // {flour: 250g}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7088

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support for Pairs in the core library. However if you find yourself doing this type of thing often, you could write a utility library. For example:

```
library pairs;

class Pair<K,V> {
  Pair(this.k, this.v)
    final K k;
    final V v;
    String toString() => '($k, $v)';
}

Iterable<Pair> asPairs(Map map) => map.keys.map((k) => new Pair(k, map[k]));

Map fromPairs(Iterable<Pair> pairs) => new Map.fromIterables(
    pairs.map((p) => p.k),
    pairs.map((p) => p.v));
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import 'src/pairs.dart';

Map flour = fromPairs(asPairs(ingredients).where((p) => p.v == '250g'));

print(flour); // {flour: 250g}
```

Perhaps this is something that could be contributed to the [quiver package](https://github.com/google/quiver-dart), a set of non-core utilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a map property to get all Map [entries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.1/dart-core/Map/entries.html).

So you can do:

```
void main() {
    Map ingredients = {
    'flour': '250g',
    'butter': '50g',
    'egg': 1,
    'water': '0.2l'
  };

  var flour = Map.fromEntries(
    ingredients
      .entries
      .where((e) => e.value == '250g'),
  );
  
  print(flour);
}
```

You would play with `e.key` if you were interested in the key's value.

Concerning a reduce method, you could use the `fold` method on the filtered entries List.